# Add table to SPDatabase object

Tags: sharepoint

I have created a database using a SPDatabase class.
How can i add a table to it?
and how to execute SQL queries in this database?

Thanx....

Answer (score 0):

Create a seperate, additional database for your custom data to use in SharePoint and just connect it like you do with any ASP.NET database.